# How to access camera on a windows tablet or attached web cams using Windows Form Application (Not WPF)?

Tags: c#, winforms, tablet, tablet-pc

I am trying to develop a Windows Form Application (not WPF) where I would require to preview numbers of cameras available on a tablet or PC, take pictures and then save the pictures in the device. 
I am very new to this kind of application development and recently came accross Media Capture but I can not find a good lead to start with.

Can anyone let me know how to approach or how can I build the application with the aforementioned features or provide a good lead??

P.S. Found a good example on https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/media-capture-sample-adf87622/ but it uses XML not the Win Form Application type.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of cameras do you have? If the cameras support onvif, then there is a good [onvif camera software](http://www.camera-sdk.com) you could try. You can handle many cameras with it, you can take snapshots so I guess it could work for you.